# BiConsumer to use the first type to set its field using the second type

Tags: java, java-8

I saw a Function that will accept a class instance and call its get method and return a string.  getData() will return a list of Functions.

```
ClassA instance = ...
for (Function<ClassA, String> method : getData()) {
    String result = method.apply(instance);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Is it possible to have a BiConsumer that will accept an instance and call its set method and use the 2nd type value?
I mean I have a ClassB which is a list.  I have to iterate through this list and use the value to set the fields in ClassA.

Comment: Please elaborate. There are too many "and" but I still don't get what you want.

Comment: That's possible, yes. Have you tried it out?

Comment: Yes: Assuming class `Foo` with `setName(String)`, you can do `BiConsumer<Foo, String> bc = (f, s) -> f.setName(s)`, which can also be written using method reference, i.e. `BiConsumer<Foo, String> bc = Foo::setName`

Comment: I actually am not sure, i thought of creating this List<BiConsumer<ClassA, ClassB>> getData() {return Arrays.asList(ClassA::setFieldA)} but i think it's wrong.  i am thinking of iterating through the ClassB list, and for each item, i will use its value to set to the field of ClassA